# How common is it in STEM fields in the US that the tenure track offer goes to the second person in the list?

Tags: faculty-application, tenure-track, interview

I had a tenure track interview at an R1 university a few weeks ago, and today the department chair wrote to me that

> We were impressed with your candidacy and still have the possibility of making an offer of a position, but you were not identified as our top candidate.

Firstly, in your experience either as someone in the search committee or as an applicant, do they send this kind of email to any person who isn't the first choice (all other short-listed candidates), or only to the second person?

Secondly, in STEM fields, (more specifically physics) how probable is it that the offer can go to the second person? With my limited experience in the US system (I moved here less than two years ago), my understanding has been so far that getting an in-person interview is so tough, getting an offer is tougher, so it's not very probable that people get more than one offer and decline the other one. Is this a correct statement?

Comment: The department chair was unprofessional.  Telling someone you're not their first choice and then offering them a job is not an encouraging way to hire.

Comment: Yes, traditionally this has not been done, but actually I think being transparent is a good practice.  Suppose you weren't told anything and then got an offer 4 weeks later.  The only possibilities for the delay are that you are the second choice, or the university has very slow hiring processes.  I wouldn't care about being the second choice, but I would be concerned if the university has bad bureaucratic processes.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderWoo, this is also a very good point. I also don't care being the second person, given that all the other short-listed people are amazing and deserve an offer. I also wasn't sure this email means that there might be a chance that I'm second, or it's common to send this to everyone in the list. But if I understood you correctly the whole thing is uncommon, so I can't read much into this, right?

Comment: Thanks @AnonymousPhysicist for the answer. I still don't know how to feel about this. I considered this as an unofficial rejection email, but not as a hope that "you might still get an offer".

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist He gave information, what might be unvaluably important for the OP. My first insight is not about the professionality/unprofessionality scale, my first insight is that the Prof was very, very helpful to the OP by giving him information about the decision mechanism (and its result). Of course, only if the feedback was not a politeness formula, but the reality.

Comment: I had the same experience, and I much preferred it to the endless silence I got from most of my applications. I don’t know why people think it would be so offensive to hear that you weren’t the top choice; I think most of us understand that faculty hiring decisions are complicated negotiations among many people involving many factors, and that it’s not a judgement of personal value to put you second. (Anyway, I learned this about three different jobs I’d applied for, was eventually offered two of them, and found out that the same person had been first choice at both of those.)

Comment: As far as the comments that telling someone they aren't first choice is insulting, nearly all searches will end in one of two outcomes: the posting attracted more hire-worthy candidates than open positions, or there are fewer hire-worthy candidates than open positions (the other outcome being that the numbers match exactly which is rare).  The former case is far more complementary to the runners-up than the second case.

Comment: Note that at least the quoted statement does not say that you are ranked second, it just says that you are not first. In my slightly cynical view this can just as well be a polite no than a statement that you barely missed.

Comment: @xLeitix this is indeed my suspicion and one of my questions. I don't know they would write this to anyone in the list, or just to the second person, and this is why I asked it here.

Comment: I was hired once for a tenure-track position.  I assumed that my presentation must have went over well, but I was hired for other reasons that are complicated.  For a non-academic job, I was clearly the 2nd choice (or 3rd), but I was hired, and glad to have the job.

Comment: Q:  Are you asking about your probability of getting a job you want, or what you should do if you are offered the job (i.e. would this interaction make you NOT want to take the job)?

Comment: @JosephDoggie my question was really what I asked. I didn't know how common or rare it is that people in the waitlist are contacted by the chair at the same time the offer is made. I also didn't know (and many comments here helped to clarify) how common it is that the top candidates get more than one offer and would be able to decline. As I mentioned in my question it was more as a general question and not for my specific case.

Answer (score 22):

I have never heard of anyone sending an email to a candidate telling them they like someone else better but if that other candidate turns them down, they might hire them as a second choice.  (Who wants to be told they were a second choice?  It strikes me as a pretty odd recruiting scheme.)

But I can tell you that top candidates get lots of offers and they can only accept one.  So, even top 10 R1 departments (like the one I was in at Michigan) routinely strike out on many of their offers and have to work down their list or accept that they just couldn't hire the people they wanted.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I'm not sure this is common to send such emails or not, this is also my first experience.

Comment: The formulation in the OP was a bit weird, but in general I don't think it's that rare to tell a candidate that they're a second-choice. Something along the lines of "You are our second-choice, and we have sent an offer to our first-choice. If they decline our offer of fail to reply within a week, then we'll offer you the position.". It's an honest answer. Better than not informing the candidate at all, and making them wait an extra week before telling them they don't get the job.

Comment: In Germany it quite usual that one knows if one is hired as second or third on the list. Maybe even the norm...

Comment: "Who wants to be told they were a second choice?" Well I would not mind hearing that from an R1 university. Why should the applicant expect to be told that he is the super-best, especially given the scale of the competition for STEM academic positions?

Comment: @КряжевАрсений Okay, but at Michigan, when they decided to make an offer, they generally asked at a dept faculty meeting that anyone with time should reach out to candidate to express unbridled enthusiasm.  (They still lost out a lot of the time.)  Apparently, the practice of telling candidates they're a second choice is more common than I had imagined.  At Michigan, to the best of my knowledge, they never did that and instead just stalled the second choice, e.g., by telling them decisions weren't yet final.

Comment: @Dirk I think the difference is that in Germany the "Dreierliste", the list of the top 3 candidates for a professorship, is an official document that needs to be created and forwarded to the administration which then formally decides and sends the offer. Even if that information is not publicly available, a loosing candidate could theoretically sue to get access to that list, so you might as well tell them. In contrast, elsewhere the second place might only be finally decided on when the first candidate declines, which would give everyone some plausible deniability.

Comment: @mlk: I think it's rather a cultural difference, you know, "unbridled enthusiasm" in the US vs. "directness" in German-speaking countries. Having lived both in the US and in Austria, I can confirm that this is not just a stereotype, but a cultural norm that people have come to expect and rely upon.

Answer (score 11):

My experience (in physics) is that:

- such an email is unusual, or at least unusually blunt.  Typically it’s not necessarily hard to figure out who’s shortlisted if units keep a public list of seminars.  Candidates can often figure out for themselves the relative rankings from the time it takes the unit to get in touch with candidates, but it is rare for this information to be volunteered so explicitly in an email.
- It is not *that* rare for selection committees to miss out in their preferred candidates, especially these days. Top tier candidates will statistically get multiple offers as they will be at the top of many lists.  Offers are declined for multiple legitimate reasons, including incompatible deadlines, startup, start dates etc.

I have come to believe that this internal ranking does not matter much.
My observations are that these rankings are often “political”; committee members may support one rather than another candidate for a number of irrational reasons.  Also, offering to person A over person B does not guarantee that person A will do better,  no more than being drafted in the second round means a player will do less well than another drafter in round 1.  It all depends on the individual.

Unless a unit is truly desperate, they will not offer a job to an inferior candidate: after all the University is about to invest in someone that could work there for 30+ years, so it’s usually better to cancel the search than hire a dud if you cannot find someone that will fit the job.

Thus: the competition is so intense these days that if you get an offer you are very much likely deserving of the position, irrespective of the original ranking.

Answer (score 8):

In physics it would be very rare for a postdoc seeking their first professorship to have two offers at the same time.  Offers can be turned down because the university does not offer enough money, either for salary or research.  This is rare.  The only case I'm personally familiar with was not technically a physicist.

People who already are permanent professors and seek a position at another university always have two offers: they can choose to keep their current job.  That's when they occasionally turn down job offers.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. This is also what I have observed so far. Just getting an interview is extremely difficult, let alone getting more than one simultaneous offers.

Comment: In math years ago we had a first choice turn us down. We were clearly a relatively likely "yes" for him - when we made the offer we suspected he might turn us down in favor of a better offer. That said, the job market is much tighter now.

Comment: At Michigan in the CSE (computer science and engineering) department where I worked, they constantly lost out to other schools fighting over new AI PhDs from Stanford, the one school they thought was better than Michigan.  Other schools apparently also thought AI PhDs from Stanford were the cat's meow.

Comment: I'm not sure how common it is in physics, so I guess it's safer to assume it's not super probable the job could go to the second person.

Comment: I’m very surprised, in math most people who get a TT job have multiple offers.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton The job market for AI PhDs is completely different from the job market for physiccs PhDs.

Comment: It is not *that* rare.  See this rumour mill site (archived to last year to show who was offered and the outcomes): http://particle.physics.ucdavis.edu/rumor/doku.php?id=archive:2021. You can browse previous years.  Admittedly this does not comprehensive covers universities, positions or fields, and the candidates shortlisted are pretty much all stellar, but clearly the top candidates at one place will not so rarely be ranked at the top elsewhere, and as mentioned elsewhere these top tier candidates can only accept one position.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero It's also well known that candidates send false information to rumor mills.

Comment: True but not in a systematic way.  My experience is that the rumour mills are largely fed by faculty, not by prospective candidates.  In a way there is nothing to hide in most cases, and without necessarily being broadcasted the shortlist is rarely guarded as closely as the Kremlin codes.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero thanks for your comment. The rumor mill couldn't give me enough information, while it's still very useful, at this point the information I have from the words of mouth from people is a lot more than what the rumor mill is showing. But my questions were a bit more general to understand the situation better, because as you said the names there are usually stellar candidates :)

Answer (score 8):

As I read the question, you were a final round candidate.  The message means that (a) you are not being given an offer at this time, and (b) if enough other final round candidates decline, you will be given an offer.  Note that there are usually only 2-4 (and most frequently 3) final round candidates for a single position, so "enough" is rarely more than 3.

(Note I think it's much better to give candidates this information rather than the other usual alternative, which is to tell candidates in this position no information at all for a few weeks.)

As far as how likely it is that the candidates preferred to you all decline, this very highly depends on how many other positions with similar hiring preferences there are, and how attractive the offer is.  Even when there are many more applicants in the market than jobs, it can frequently happen that several jobs want the same candidate, because they happen to all be looking for similar things in candidates, in which case their evaluations of candidates are quite likely to coincide.  Then it comes down to how likely that position is to be the candidate's first choice.  We have had searches here where all our final round candidates declined our offer one after another, and we had to reopen the final round.  (In fact, that's how I was hired.)  The market is tighter now, but that also means people who might not have applied for our job 10 years ago would apply now, and we are still probably close to the last choice among our most attractive applicants.  (For one thing, we typically are only able to offer about 80% of the salary many competitors can offer.)

Answer (score 5):

(In Sweden) If the university is funded by tax payers, all notes, rankings and evaluations must be available to public. This is to ensure there's no corruption. Hence, making the rank public is not strange from that perspective.

Comment: is this before or *after* the competition is closed?

Comment: good point - I suppose it is only required to be available after.

Comment: In Canada we certainly have to *destroy* our personal notes, although I think a digest/summary of the unattributed comments is kept for the records.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: Sure, in Sweden also, there are two different principles involved; GDPR, for protecting the individuals privacy, but also a principle that all information which underlies government decisions must be made public. But it all gets complicated when international relations are at stake: https://apnews.com/article/f3219da7e5b9ee74e7002746255dc9a6

Answer (score 3):

I have seen many of these instances even for my personal applications. First, they really like your application, which includes CV, research, personality, and many other things. For sure, they have given the offer to someone else but have seen some degree of uncertainty with that person due to many factors such as asking for a higher salary, spouse hiring, a larger startup, a higher rank if the position is an open-rank one and so many other behind-the-scenes variables. At the same time, they also don't want to lose you! So, they just wanted to avoid a situation where you accept an offer from somewhere else if the first candidate does not accept the offer. They may think that you will not accept their offer in that case and are just trying to buy some time.